# How to give users with role Role2 the right to edit only user accounts with role Role1

Tags: users

I need to make a user edit users that have a specific role.
In fact we have two user roles here.

- Role1 -> is able to edit a particular kind of node
- Role2 -> is only able to  administer users with the role "Role1".

My question: how to give users of Role2 access to edit only user accounts of Role1?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [Administer Users by Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole) module.

> This module allows site builders to set up fine-grained permissions
>   for allowing "sub-admin" users to edit and delete other users — more
>   specific than Drupal Core's all-or-nothing 'administer users'
>   permission. It also provides and enforces a 'create users' permission.

One of the extra permissions that this module provides is

**Edit users with custom roles** - *Allows editing of any authenticated user with the specified role.*

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module which is like a "little brother" of [Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og). It only started in D7 and with a D8 version in the pipeline. Personally I'm more and more considering/using it as a potential alternative for the [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) module. And since it is all entity based, there are lots of ways it can be used in combination with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module also.

Specific to your question here, I think what is going to help you a lot is the **Group member profiles** sub-module.

For way more details about this module, refer to its [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2666972) pages, such as the [Group HowTos](https://www.drupal.org/node/2692869) subpage of it.

**Note**: Your question doesn't specify which version you are using, but this answer applies for both D7 and D8.

Comment: The potential of `Group` module got me curious, so I spent a few minutes looking into the functionality that it provides. Thank you for sharing this, I already have a few ideas how I can make some projects of mine more robust by using it. On a side note, it provides advanced content access opportunities but doesn't cover the ability to give a specific user role an ability to edit user accounts of a specific role and not all others. So, it appears that the combination of both `Group` and `Administer Users by Role` modules should give the OP the desired flexibility. thoughts?